# Найти маршрут в квадрате

Tags: c, алгоритм

Найти маршрут в квадрате, который начинался бы и заканчивался в ячейке 1. При этом посетить все клетки по одному разу, не попадая в черные.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#define N 8


int search_path(int matrix[N][N], int y);


int main()
{
    int Array[N][N] = {{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0},
                       {0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},
                       {0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0}};
     int visited[N];                  

    int i,j;
    search_path(Array[N][N], y)

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)

            printf("%d ",Array[i][j]);
            printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}

int search_path(int y)
{
   int visited[N];
   int k;
   visited[y] = 1;

   for(k=0; k<N; k++)
    {
        if(matrix[y][k] && !visited[k])
        return k;
    }



}
```

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы проходить через клетки пошагово и не повторять их и вернуться в точку 1

Comment: ну на самом деле это в общем виде гамильтонов цикл и он за вменяемое время не решается... Вы можете попробовать сделать рекурсию с отсечением но тут как пойдёт...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку только что развлекался другим лабиринтом, так и быть, держите...

http://ideone.com/AjHRqr

Путь нарисуйте сами :-) Честно говоря, проверять лень...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int Tgt = 110;
const int I   = Tgt;

int m[8][8]={
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0},
    {0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},
    {0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0}
};

struct Coord
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    Coord(int x = 0, int y = 0):x(x),y(y){}
};

const int STOP = 54; //64 - 10;

Coord path[STOP];

bool step(int x, int y, int level)
{

    if (level == STOP-1)
    {
        if (x == 0 && y == 1)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < level; ++i)
            {
                cout << "(" << path[i].x  << "," << path[i].y << ") - ";
            }
            cout << "(0,1)\n";
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    m[x][y] = 1;

    path[level] = Coord(x,y);

    // Up
    if (y > 0 && m[x][y-1] == 0)
    {
        if (step(x,y-1,level+1)) return true;
    }
    // Dn
    if (y < 7 && m[x][y+1] == 0)
    {
        if (step(x,y+1,level+1)) return true;
    }
    // Lt
    if (x > 0 && m[x-1][y] == 0)
    {
        if (step(x-1,y,level+1)) return true;
    }
    // Rt
    if (x < 7 && m[x+1][y] == 0)
    {
        if (step(x+1,y,level+1)) return true;
    }
    m[x][y] = 0;
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    step(1,0,1);
}
```

Все ж не утерпел, нарисовал :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное, если не сложно можна написать эту структуру на Си ? struct Coord
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    Coord(int x = 0, int y = 0):x(x),y(y){}
};

Comment: Да просто напишите структуру, которая инициализируется нулевыми значениями...